# Kivy FloatLayout centers children?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to use `FloatLayout` in Kivy to manually position some images, but the origin point `(0, 0)` seems to be at the center of the screen, and not the bottom left corner as described by the documentation. I've tried setting the `pos`, `pos_hint`, and `left` properties of the image to get it *in the bottom left corner*, but nothing is working.

Frustratingly, when I draw a rectangle there with `canvas.after`, it draws correctly in the bottom left corner. My kv code:

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas.after:
        Line:
            rectangle: [0, 0, 10, 10]
    Image:
        id: sprite
        pos_hint_x: None
        pos_hint_y: None
        pos: 0, 0
        size: 32, 32
        source: 'atlas://img/sprites/fuzzy_dragon'
```

The image draws dead center in the screen, with the rectangle in the bottom left corner. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change `FloatLayout` to `RelativeLayout `

Comment: @Juggernaut what for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **`size_hint_*`**, not `pos_hint_*` for disabling relative sizing i.e.:

```
size_hint: None, None
size: 32, 32
```

otherwise it'll take the whole screen thus you think it's centered. Well, it *is*, but not for the reasons you think it is :P

`pos_hint` is a [*dictionary*](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint) and works differently.

In future debug layouts and elements with [Inspector](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.inspector.html)(`python main.py -m inspector`).

Comment: That did it, thank you. What was throwing me off was that the buttons weren't automatically taking the whole screen, so they positioned properly, but the other widgets were being affected.